# Why does not process a $.getJSON function if file located not in project folder?

Tags: jquery, getjson

Please, could anybody answer what difference between this functions:

```
$.getJSON("jsonData.json", function(data){
   //function will be here
});

and

$.getJSON("http://www.some_site.com/jsonData.json", function(data){
   //function will be here
});
```

In first case function works OK (file located on computer in project's folder). But in second - NO. What is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the Same-Origin Policy, you cannot use AJAX to read a file from a different domain.

The whole point of `$.getJSON()` is that it uses JSONP to bypass this restriction.
That only works if the remote URL accepts JSONP requests, which yours does not.